# C++ member access from a derived class of a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class

Long story short, what I want here is to declare a templated type in a base class and be able to access that type `A<T>` such that the base class `B` contains it and the derived class `C` is able to access it as `C::A<T>`. I did try declaring an `int` inside of `class B` and that can be accessed from the derived `C` class as `C::int`, here's the error!

```
||In constructor ‘D::D()’:|
|74|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘A<C*>’ and ‘A<B*>’)|
|4|note: candidate: A<C*>& A<C*>::operator=(const A<C*>&)|
|4|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A<B*>’ to ‘const A<C*>&’|
```

And this is the code that does compile ( comment `A<B*> i;` and uncomment `A<C*> i;` to get the error).

```
#include <iostream>
//class with a template parameter
template <class a>
class A
{
    private:

        int somevalue;

    public:

    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<somevalue<<std::endl;
    }
};

//1. could forward declare
class C;
class B
{
    protected:

        A<B*> i;
        //2. and then use
        //A<C*> i;

    public:

        B(){}
        ~B(){}
        A<B*> get()
        {
            return i;
        }

        /*
        //3. use this return instead
        A<C*> get()
        {
            return i;
        }
        */
};
//specialization of B that uses B's methods variables
class C : public B
{
    protected:

    public:

        C(){}
        virtual ~C(){}
        void method()
        {
            B::i.print();
        }
};
//class D that inherits the specialization of C
class D : public C
{
    private:

        A<B*> i;//works
        //4. but I want the inherited type to work like
        //A<C*> i;// so that the type C* is interpreted as B*

    public:

    D()
    {
        this->i = C::i;
    }
    ~D(){}
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    D* d = new D();

    delete d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This would solve the whole problem but it's not portable and C++ like." explain?

Comment: I don't want to declare that class name every time I want to use that class. isn't there a different method of instantiating this, given that I would want a header file stored somewhere without know its contents.

Comment: Is this the long-time favorite of MyTemplate<Base> and MyTemplate<Derived> types aren't related by inheritance problem?  I can't actually understand your question.   It's very long and rambling and you have WAY more code in your example than you need.

Comment: Is it, is there a solution, cause i've tried for hours now, mark it as duplicate if you like! Yes that does sound like the problem.

Comment: "Is this the long-time favorite of MyTemplate<Base> and MyTemplate<Derived> types aren't related by inheritance problem? I can't actually understand your question. It's very long and rambling and you have WAY more code in your example than you need" I know, but the code does explain it better. I guess.

Comment: Template<X> and Template<Y> don't inherit from each other, regardless of the relationship between X and Y -- unless the template itself explicitly states the relationship..template<class T> Template<T> : public Template<Y> {}; or some such.

Comment: So the only solution is to declare everything with that template argument in the derived class as well right, then what's the point of inheritance?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually understand what your goal is, so I can't tell you how to change your code to suit it.   I can tell you that you don't need this behavior to achieve your goal... but I don't know what option would be best for you based on the example above.  I also don't seem to be able to find a dupe, though I know I've seen it many times in the past.

Comment: The goal is the code above, generally written as simple as possible. What I could do is write the method in the derived class for the `get()` function for the template argument of the derived class and that would solve the problem.

Comment: It would probably be better to write an example main function with the wanted behavior ... it's absolutely impossible to get what you're trying to achieve here ...

Comment: You mean to get rid of `class D` ?

Comment: "You get a compiler error saying it cannot convert B* to C* obviously." That's not what it's saying. It's saying you can't change an `A<B*>` to a `A<C*>`. There is a relationship between `B` and `C`, but the same can't be said for two different specializations of `A`.

Comment: `A` doesn't use its template argument so I don't understand what you mean by "I want `A<B*> i` to work like `A<C*> i`". All types `A<T>` work the same way.

Comment: So there is basically no solution to this problem and I'm just misusing C++?

Comment: No, there is no problem (or rather your description makes no sense). Can you show actual code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: That is the code, that's all I have!

Comment: Then the solution is to get rid of the template and make `A` a plain class.

Comment: Btw: from `B*` to `C*` isn't that good an idea either, you need to explicitly downcast (and check whether it succeed).

Comment: @pandoragami No, it isn't. `A` is a class template you created in your code ("*that's all I have!*"). If you have some other, actual code, you need to post that.

Answer (score 2):

> But okay what if we tried this `std::list<template parameter> LIST` and then plug that in? That's the problem `A<T>` is `std::list`.

As far as I understand your issue now you seem to have a `std::list<Base *>` (renamed `B` to `Base` for clarity) and want to fill an `std::list<Concrete*>` (renamed `C` to `Concrete`, it's derived from `Base`) with it.

For that you need to iterate over the `Base*` pointers, checking for each whether it can be *downcast* to a `Concrete*` and if so adding it to the `std::list<Concrete*>`. You need to think about what to do if the downcast fails, too.

For all of this to work your `Base` needs to be a *polymorphic base class*, that is it must contain a virtual member function (don't forget to make the destructor virtual). Also note that this sounds like a catastrophe waiting to happen in terms of managing ownership of those pointers.

```
template<typename Base, typename Concrete>
std::list<Concrete*> downcast_list (std::list<Base*> const & bases) {
 std::list<Concrete*> result;
  for (auto const base_ptr : bases) {
    Concrete * concrete_ptr = dynamic_cast<Concrete*>(base_ptr);
    if (concrete_ptr != nullptr) {
      result.push_back(concrete_ptr);
    } else {
      // Error or ignore?
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note: a more idiomatic version of this would use iterators.

Answer (score 1):

I found the pattern to my problem, it's actually really simple and it serves as the base for encapsulating a class type `a` (which is a template parameter to be passed around, try looking at my question as a reference to `class a`). The pattern is shown below, it's generally what I wanted. I found it on this webpage [Using Inheritance Between Templates chapter 7.5 from the book entitled OBJECT-ORIENTED
SOFTWARE DESIGN
and CONSTRUCTION
with C++ by Dennis Kafura](http://www.prenhall.com/divisions/esm/app/kafura/secure/chapter7/html/7.5_inheritance.htm). I'll copy it below the edited code for the sake of future reference in case anyone else needs it.

```
template <class a> 
class B 
{
    private:      

    public:

        B();     
        ~B();
};

template <class a> 
class C : public B<a>
{
   public:
    C();
    ~C();
};
```

This is the code it was adapted from.

```
template <class QueueItem> class Queue 
{
   private:

      QueueItem buffer[100];
      int head, tail, count;

    public:
                Queue();
      void      Insert(QueueItem item);
      QueueItem Remove();
               ~Queue();
};

template <class QueueItem> class InspectableQueue : public Queue<QueueItem>
{
   public:
               InspectableQueue();
     QueueItem Inspect();  // return without removing the first element
              ~InspectableQueue();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this:

> > ```
> > #include <iostream>
> > //class with a template parameter
> > template <class a>
> > class A {
> > private:    
> >     int somevalue;    
> > public:    
> >     A(){}
> >     ~A(){}
> >     void print() {
> >         std::cout<<somevalue<<std::endl;
> >     }
> > };
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > //1. could forward declare
> > class C;
> > class B {
> > protected:    
> >     A<B*> i;
> >     //2. and then use
> >     //A<C*> i;    
> > public:    
> >     B(){}
> >     ~B(){}
> >     A<B*> get() {
> >         return i;
> >     }
> >
> >     /*/3. use this return instead
> >     A<C*> get() {
> >        return i;
> >     } */
> > };
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > //specialization of B that uses B's methods variables
> > class C : public B {
> > protected:
> > public:    
> >     C(){}
> >     virtual ~C(){}
> >     void method() {
> >         B::i.print();
> >     }
> > };
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> > //class D that inherits the specialization of C
> > class D : public C {
> > private:   
> >     A<B*> i;//works
> >     //4. but I want the inherited type to work like
> >     //A<C*> i;// so that the type C* is interpreted as B*
> > public:    
> >     D() {
> >         this->i = C::i;
> >     }
> >     ~D(){}
> > };
> > ```
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> >    int main() {
> >     D* d = new D();    
> >     delete d;    
> >     return 0;
> > }
> > ```

To Something Like This:

```
#include <iostream>

//class with a template parameter
template <typename T>
class Foo {
private:    
    T value_;    
public:    
    Foo(){} // Default
    Foo( T value ) : value_(value) {}
    ~Foo(){}
    void print() {
        std::cout<< value_ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

---

```
class Derived;
class Base {
protected:
    Foo<Base*> foo_;
    Base(){} // Default;
    virtual ~Base(){}

    // Overload This Function
    template<typename T = Base>
    /*virtual*/ Foo<T*> get();

    /*virtual*/ Foo<Base*> get() { return this->foo_; }
    /*virtual*/ Foo<Derived*> get();
};
```

---

```
class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    void func() {
        Base::foo_.print();
    }
    void Foo<Derived*> get() override { return this->foo_; } 
 };
```

And this is as about as far as I could get trying to answering your question...

- There are objects that you are not using in your code
- There are methods that aren't being called.
- It is kind of hard to understand the direction/indirection 
   of what you mean to do with the inheritance tree.
- You are inheriting from a `base` class without a `virtual destructor`
- And probably a few other things that I can not think of off the top of my head right now.

I'd be more than willing to try and help you out; but this is as far as I can go with what you currently are showing.

**EDIT** -- I made changes to the `base & derived` classes and removed the `virtual` keyword to the overloaded function template declarations - definitions belonging to those classes.

Comment: @pandoragami no problem at all; I'm self taught, never had any formal training nor any college courses, never had someone sit there and teach it all to me. I had to find what few books I could get, I had to read a bunch of mundane and archaic type websites going as far back as the mid to late 90s even when `ftp` sites were still widely used. I had to do a bunch of trial and errors and many failures just to even get simple things to work. Then it took time to learn the language; and I'm still currently learning. Sometimes helping others helps me to learn for I have to stop and think about it.

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't work, you cannot use virtuals and templates together.

Comment: Oh; yeah... I'm still learning templates myself, they are one of the harder parts of the C++ language to master. Yes you can leave the destructor as virtual and any non template methods or functions as virtual but for any overloaded template functions belonging to the class; virtual storage won't work.

Comment: I added my answer to my question, it sort of solved ( not exactly)  my problem and didn't need anything overly complicated. It seems though that there is no real easy method of inheriting a datatype with a template parameter and it must be defined (specialized) in the derived class no matter what. My solution only encapsulates the datatype as a template parameter so it's passed around instead! It's better than nothing and that's the best it can get using simple C++ coding.